# Chart.js extra undefined column

Tags: javascript, html, charts, bar-chart, chart.js

I have download a examples of chart.js from https://codeload.github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/zip/master and modified example of bar chart, after I executing the code, an extra column get generated in bar chart.
Is that a bug in the chart.js? or Is there a problem with code?
Please suggest me any other alternative to draw a bar chart, if it's a chart.js issue.
Thanks

[image]

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Bar Chart</title>
        <script src="../Chart.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="width: 50%">
            <canvas id="canvas" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
        </div>


    <script>
    var randomScalingFactor = function(){ return Math.round(Math.random()*100)};

    var barChartData = {
        labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","Jun"],
        datasets : [
            {
                fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
                highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
                highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
            },
            {
                fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
                highlightFill : "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
                highlightStroke : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
            },
            {
                fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
                highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
                highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                data: [randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor()]
            }
        ]

    }
    window.onload = function(){
        var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
        window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData, {
            responsive : true
        });
    }

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one extra point in each of your datasets (7 instead of the 6 in your labels). Just remove the last points from each of your 3 datasets.